Databricks DLT Online Table with VNnet Enable on Blob Storage Get 403 Issue
I am trying to create an online table in a Unity catalog. However, I get a GET, 403 error.
DataPlaneException: Failed to start the DLT service on cluster . Please check the stack trace below or driver logs for more details.
com.databricks.pipelines.execution.service.UCContextInitializationException: Failed to initialize the UCContext
com.databricks.pipelines.common.CustomException: [DLT ERROR CODE: EXECUTION_SERVICE_STARTUP_FAILURE.STORAGE_PERMISSION_ISSUE] Operation failed: "This request is not authorized to perform this operation.", 403, GET
This error only happens when I set my ADLS Gen 2 Networking Public network access settings to Enabled from selected virtual networks and IP addresses.
The online table gets created When I Enable it from all networks.
I have the correct access control using the unity-catalog-access-connector with Storage Blob Data Contributor.
My Databricks workspace is set up in a VNet with two subnets: the private and the public. These two subnets are white-listed in the network settings of my ADSL Gen2 in the Virtual Networks section of the Networking settings.
Yet, the only way I can set up the DLT Online Table is by setting my Blob storage to Enable it form all networks. How do I do this without Enabling it to all networks?

I figured it out. It was because of the Network Connectivity Configurations since it uses Serverless SQL Wharehouse to set it up. I did not have one set up with a private endpoint connection to the ADLS Gen2.  I followed the instructions here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/security/network/serverless-network-security/serverless-private-link and it is now working with the VNet integrated.
